If a slice of a 4 dimensional metric violates an energy condition, does the 4 dim metric violate it aswell?
I 'm currently studying analogue gravity see this paper for a review. Here a 2+1 dimensional metric is derived:
$$
ds^2 = -dt^2 + (dr - \frac{A}{r} dt)^2 + (r d\theta - \frac{B}{r} dt)^2 
$$
Now it turns out that this metric violates all the energy conditions (NEC and SEC as computed in 2+1 gravity) and my question is; does this mean that if we extend this 2+1 dimensional metric to 3+1 dimensions that the 3+1 metric will also violate NEC and SEC?
Any literature on this topic would also be grealy appreciated, as I have yet to find any.
Extra:
An extension would be for example:
$$
ds^2 = -dt^2 + (dr - \frac{A}{r} dt)^2 + (r d\theta - \frac{B}{r} dt)^2  + dz^2
$$
I furthermore use the following definition of an extension:
Definition[Extension]
Let $g$ be a 3+1 dimensional metric with coordinates $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ and let $h$ a 2+1 dimensional metric with coordinates $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$. we call $g$ an extension of $h$ if there exists a $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
g_{\alpha \beta} |_{x^3 = \theta} \delta^{\alpha}_a \delta^{\beta }_b =h_{ab}
$$
